# How do I improvise a variable that tracks players' health? - Python

Tags: python

This is a short-project for a 2-player text-based turn-based fighting game, where you can control the name of the players as well as the "power level" or magnitude behind an attack (from 1-50). The higher the magnitude the lower the chance. Where it's 100% - the magnitude selected. The higest damage, or 50? You'll have a 50% chance to land it. 1 damage? 99% chance. And so on.

The damage calculation affecting the health bar **is** where the issue mostly resides in.

To put it simply, with the code presented here, I keep running to the same error assuming the attack **doesn't** miss:

```
import random
        
def get_valid_name(existing_names):
    while True:
        name = input("Please type your hero’s name: ")
        if name and name not in existing_names:
            return name
        elif name in existing_names:
            print(f"{name} is taken, please choose another name!")

def perform_attack(attacker: any,
                   defender: any) -> None:
    magnitude = int(input(f"————— {attacker} Attacks !! —————\nChoose your attack magnitude between 1 and 50: "))
    
    if 1 <= magnitude <= 50:
        success_chance = random.randint(1, 100)
        if success_chance <= (100 - magnitude):
            print(f"{attacker} hits {magnitude} damage!!!")
            "defender_health"[0] -= "int";magnitude
        else:
            print(f"Ooopsy! {attacker} missed the attack!")
        print_status(attacker, defender)
    else:
        print("The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50. Choose your attack magnitude between 1 and 50:")

def print_status(player1, player2):
    print(f"\n{player1} {' ' * 57} {player2}\nHP[{player1_health[0]}]: {'I' * (player1_health[0] // 2)} "
          f"HP[{player2_health[0]}]: {'I' * (player2_health[0] // 2)}")

def coin_toss():
    return random.choice([player1_name, player2_name])

def game_over():
    print("#" * 70)
    print(f"{winner} Wins !!!")
    print("#" * 70)
    print("\nThanks for playing! See you again!")

player1_name = get_valid_name([])
player2_name = get_valid_name([player1_name])

player1_health = [100]
player2_health = [100]

current_player = coin_toss()
print(f"Coin toss result: {current_player} starts first!")
print_status(player1_name, player2_name)

while True:
    if current_player == player1_name:
        perform_attack(player1_name, player2_name)
        if player2_health[0] <= 0:
            winner = player1_name
            game_over()
            break
        current_player = player2_name
    else:
        perform_attack(player2_name, player1_name)
        if player1_health[0] <= 0:
            winner = player2_name
            game_over()
            break
        current_player = player1_name

    play_again = input("Do you want to play another round (Yes or No)? ").lower()
    if play_again != 'yes':
        print("\nThanks for playing! See you again!")
        break
    else:
        player1_health = [100]
        player2_health = [100]
        current_player = coin_toss()
        print(f"Coin toss result: {current_player} starts first!")
        print_status(player1_name, player2_name)
```

The expectation was that it would end up being consistent and take away from the defending player's HP. The issue was **this** error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'str'
```

From what I understand it relates to the "defender_health"[0] being the issue. But I don't understand how to make it work.

Comment: Posting the entire traceback would be useful. However, I'm assuming the problematic line is this one: `"defender_health"[0] -= "int"`. `"defender_health"[0]` is a string and `"int"` is also a string. It isn't possible to subtract strings, hence the error. I'm not really sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: @ndc85430 I tried to write it as `"defender_health"[0] -= int(magnitude)` or even `"defender_health"[0] -= magnitude ` as I've had written it was an integer with the 'magnitude = int(input("..."))'

The same still persisted, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: `player1_health = [100]` What is the purpose of using a list here?  Why not use a plain integer, like this `player1_health = 100`?

Comment: @Esmund but that still doesn't make any sense - `"defender_health"[0]` evaluates to the string `"d"` and regardless of the type of `magnitude`, you can't subtract something from a string. Is there supposed to be a _variable_ called `defender_health` (as opposed to that string literal)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem you're having is that in the line `"defender_health"[0] -= int(magnitude)`, you're telling Python to take the first character of the string "defender_health", which is "d", and subtract the magnitude from "d", which is invalid.

The most basic solution here would be to pass the the defender's health along to the `perform_attack` function so that you can access it.  I also added some error handling for the user entry and restructured the function a bit

```
def perform_attack(attacker: str, defender: str, defender_health: list) -> None:
    while True:
        try:
            magnitude = int(input(f"————— {attacker} Attacks !! —————\nChoose your attack magnitude between 1 and 50: "))
            if not 1 <= magnitude <= 50:
                raise ValueError    
        except ValueError:
            print("The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50. Choose your attack magnitude between 1 and 50:")
        else:
            break
    
    success_chance = random.randint(1, 100)
    if success_chance <= (100 - magnitude):
        print(f"{attacker} hits {magnitude} damage!!!")
        defender_health[0] -= magnitude
    else:
        print(f"Ooopsy! {attacker} missed the attack!")
        print_status(attacker, defender)

...
...
   # And then in your main game loop
while True:
    if current_player == player1_name:
        perform_attack(player1_name, player2_name, player2_health)
        if player2_health[0] <= 0:
            winner = player1_name
            game_over()
            break
        current_player = player2_name
    else:
        perform_attack(player2_name, player1_name, player1_health)
        if player1_health[0] <= 0:
            winner = player2_name
            game_over()
            break
        current_player = player1_name
```

Instead of adding a third parameter to the function, other ideas would be to change the structure of your player data so that instead of having separate variables for the player name and health,  you instead use a dict for each player such as:

```
player = {
    "name": user_input,
    "health": 100
    }

# and then reference the dictionary keys with:
player1["health"] -= magnitude
```

Or you could create a class to define a player object, and make instances of the object.  As a partial example:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.health = 100

    def damage(self, magnitude):
        self.health -= magnitude

player1 = Player(input("Player 1 name: ")
player2 = Player(input("Player 2 name: ")

def perform_attack(attacker: str, defender: str) -> None:
    while True:
        try:
            magnitude = int(input(f"————— {attacker.name} Attacks !! —————\nChoose your attack magnitude between 1 and 50: "))
            if not 1 <= magnitude <= 50:
                raise ValueError    
        except ValueError:
            print("The attack magnitude must be between 1 and 50. Choose your attack magnitude between 1 and 50:")
        else:
            break
    
    success_chance = random.randint(1, 100)
    if success_chance <= (100 - magnitude):
        print(f"{attacker.name} hits {magnitude} damage!!!")
        defender.damage(magnitude)
    else:
        print(f"Ooopsy! {attacker.name} missed the attack!")
```